How to display PcP info on a WordPress site
Does anyone know how to display on a WordPress site the CiviCRM Personal Campaign Pages, with the amount raised, number of donations and the supporter who run the PcP?
I have managed to display the amount raised and the number of donations with the Shortcode [ux_campaign_info_thermometer], but would need to link this info with the PcP supporter.
Thank you!

Not sure if there is an existing built in shortcode for all PCPs but you could create a SearchKit with a display and use the shortcode for that one ?

I think it's all in SK, just checked on dmaster and the below search would allow you to create the relevant displays

I can't set the display to bypass permissions on dmaster but with that enabled you should be able to display it publicly


Many thanks for your helpful response. I managed to create the Search Kit query and the FormBuilder (a Search Form) with "Accessible on front-end of website" enabled, but when introducing the shortcode: [civicrm component="afform" name="x"] on a WordPress page the form is not displayed. Any idea what I am missing? Thank you!

Great! Do try on the search display to toggle the bit at the top from 'Enforce permissions' to 'Bypass permissions'
